# Chrome Extension - Find Google reCAPTCHA on page

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome-extension

Is it possible to find a reCAPTCHA object in the user's active tab? If so, is it also possible to check if the captcha has been solved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it is possible to reference a recaptcha object that is on the page as well as get its "solved" value.

To get the recaptcha's "solved" value, use 
    `grecaptcha.getResponse(widgetId)` 
where widgetId is an optional parameter. If omitted, this function will retrieve the value of the page's first recaptcha.

The function `grecaptcha.render(container,parameters)` will return an ID for a recaptcha widget.

Note: the term "id" here is not the same as an HTML element ID. You need to use the Google Recaptcha Javascript API functions to get an ID for the widget.

I recommend you take a look at the Google Recaptcha Javascript API here: https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#js_api